# Avoiding Chain Redirects on AMP Page URLs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm looking for help with a chain redirect issue, please.

Desired behaviour: **example.com/foo?amp** redirects to **example.com/bar**

Current behaviour: **example.com/foo?amp** redirects to **example.com/foo** then redirects to **example.com/bar**

This is a Wordpress site.  Htaccess has the following rule, which doesn't appear to be solving the chain redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} amp
RewriteRule ^/foo$ /bar [L,R=301]
```

My htaccess kung foo is quite weak, so I'm fully expecting that I've made a mess there!

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You missed just a tiny detail to get things working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} amp
RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [L,R=301]
```

The pattern in the rewriting rule is matched against the *relative* path of the URL (`foo`, not`/foo`), when implemented in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess").

It really makes sense to read the documentation of the tools you are using for such details. As typical for OpenSource software the documentation for the apache http server and its module is of excellent quality and comes with great examples.
You want to start with here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

One could optimize above rule a bit:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^amp$
RewriteRule ^/?foo/?$ /bar [R=301,END]
```

And you should check whether you can implement such a rule in the actual http server's host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files...

Comment: Superb!  Thank you so much for you prompt and detailed response.  Have a fabulous day.