# Redirecting Amp Pages

Tags: redirect

In reference to the question asked and answered here - Would the same RewriteEngine on code work for longer string urls?
[Avoiding Chain Redirects on AMP Page URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67282287/avoiding-chain-redirects-on-amp-page-urls/77324872#77324872)

eg

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} amp

RewriteRule ^/tech/google/3-latest-tech-products$ /tech/alphabet/3-new-technologies-products [L,R=301]

I didn't want to try this in case it broke the site but I have quite a few urls in 3 and 4 redirection chains so wanted to just redirect the amp version to the final destination.

Comment: Why would it not?

Comment: I just wasn't sure if the previous reference only applied to sub-folders as the person had given foo/  - vs adding the full url string. Apologies on what is probably a very basic question. You can see I have next to no knowledge on the topic -  Thanks for the reply, and if you have anything further to add please do.